# Exclusive open excel file Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, interop

I am opening an excel file using Workbooks.Open method and writing some data in it. I ma opening in invisible mode. I am keeping the file open till application is running. but if user is opening same excel file in windows explorer, it is opening same excel process and allows to edit the file directly to the user. "MultiUserEditing" gives False value.

I want to implement that user can not open (or open in read only mode) file from windows explorer or from MS Excel if it is already opened in my application.

Thanks,

Comment: Where are you stuck? Stack Overflow users will be happy to help if you are stuck in your code, but this is not freecoders.com

Comment: @Issun, Yes, I know it is not freecoders.com. i think you did not understand the problem. I am trying to implement code such that if xls file is opened by the application, it can not be opened directly from windows explorer or can be opened in read only mode. but i am not able to find such property or method to do that using Interop class.